# Checking URLs with Python

Tags: python, url

I am trying to test an entire list of websites to see if the URLs are valid, and I want to know which ones are not.

```
import urllib2

filename=open(argfile,'r')
f=filename.readlines()
filename.close()

def urlcheck() :
    for line in f:
        try:
            urllib2.urlopen()
            print "SITE IS FUNCTIONAL"
        except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
            print(e.code)
        except urllib2.URLError, e:
            print(e.args)
urlcheck()
```

Comment: How does your code not work?

Answer (score 1):

You have to pass url

```
def urlcheck() :
    for line in f:
        try:
            urllib2.urlopen(line)
            print line, "SITE IS FUNCTIONAL"
        except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
            print line, "SITE IS NOT FUNCTIONAL"
            print(e.code)
        except urllib2.URLError, e:
            print line, "SITE IS NOT FUNCTIONAL"
            print(e.args)
        except Exception,e:
            print line, "Invalid URL"
```

**Some edge cases or things to consider**

Little bit on error codes and HTTPError

> Every HTTP response from the server contains a numeric “status code”.
>   Sometimes the status code indicates that the server is unable to
>   fulfil the request. The default handlers will handle some of these
>   responses for you (for example, if the response is a “redirection”
>   that requests the client fetch the document from a different URL,
>   urllib2 will handle that for you). For those it can’t handle, urlopen
>   will raise an HTTPError. Typical errors include ‘404’ (page not
>   found), ‘403’ (request forbidden), and ‘401’ (authentication
>   required).

Even if HTTPError is raised you may check for the error code

- So sometimes even if the URL is valid and available it may raise HTTPError with code `403`,`401` etc .
- Sometime valid urls would give `5xx` due to temporary `ServerErrors`

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to use `requests` library.

```
import requests
resp = requests.get('your url')
if not resp.ok:
    print resp.status_code
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass url as a parameter to the urlopen function.

```
import urllib2

filename=open(argfile,'r')
f=filename.readlines()
filename.close()

def urlcheck() :
    for line in f:
        try:
            urllib2.urlopen(line) # careful here
            print "SITE IS FUNCTIONAL"
        except urllib2.HTTPError, e:
            print(e.code)
        except urllib2.URLError, e:
            print(e.args)
urlcheck()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import urllib2

def check(url): 
    request = urllib2.Request(url)
    request.get_method = lambda : 'HEAD' # gets only headers without body (increase speed)
    request.add_header('Content-Encoding', 'gzip, deflate, br') # gets archived headers (increase speed)
    try:
        response = urllib2.urlopen(request)
        return response.getcode() <= 400
    except Exception:
        return False    

'''
Contents of "/tmp/urls.txt"

http://www.google.com
https://fb.com
http://not-valid
http://not-valid.nvd
not-valid
'''
filename = open('/tmp/urls.txt', 'r')
urls = filename.readlines()
filename.close()

for url in urls:
    print url + ' ' + str(check(url))
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably write it like this:

```
import urllib2

with open('urls.txt') as f:
    urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]

def urlcheck() :
    for url in urls:
        try:
            urllib2.urlopen(url)
        except (ValueError, urllib2.URLError) as e:
            print('invalid url: {}'.format(url))

urlcheck()
```

some changes from the OP's original implementation:

- use a context manager to open/close data file
- strip newlines from URLs as they are read from file
- use better variable names
- switch to more modern exception handling style
- also catch ValueError for malformed URL's
- display a more useful error message

example output:

```
$ python urlcheck.py 
invalid url: http://www.google.com/wertbh
invalid url: htp:/google.com
invalid url: google.com
invalid url: https://wwwbad-domain-zzzz.com
```